# MongoDB : error by creatig the admin user

Tags: mongodb

When i do the tutorial from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ i become everytime this error: E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:15

If i type in any command in the mongodb console, i become a error. The same  E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:15

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please show us the command you try to execute.

Comment: mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb

Comment: Have a look at all default [parameters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/), do they **all** fit in your environment? Better use a [config file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html).